# PHPUnit Stubbing A Class

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, stub

Taken From PHPUnit's ReadTheDocs page:

```
    <?php declare(strict_types=1);
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

final class StubTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testStub(): void
    {
        // Create a stub for the SomeClass class.
        $stub = $this->createStub(SomeClass::class);

        // Configure the stub.
        $stub->method('doSomething')
             ->willReturn('foo');

        // Calling $stub->doSomething() will now return
        // 'foo'.
        $this->assertSame('foo', $stub->doSomething());
    }
}
```

I am running a test very similar to this. When I execute the test runner I get an error. It can not find my SomeClass::class. What is wrong? SomeClass is in SomeClass.php and in the same directory as the pnpunit executable.

Comment: Your `phpunit` should be inside `vendor/bin`, where do you have your `phpunit` executable ? What is the namespace defined on `SomeClass` ?

Comment: i have it in ~/php_unit/tools

Comment: Share your hierarchy please, and your `compose.json` if you have one.

Comment: Hi matiaslauriti, what i was looking for is the front page of https://phpunit.de/

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.